# Laravel Eloquent : How to remove json column children key?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a jsonb column `foo` in which I would like to remove the key `bar->abc` without modifying other children keys.

I tried this:

```
MyModel::find(123)->update([
        'foo' => DB::raw("JSON_REMOVE(foo, 'bar->abc')")
    ]);
```

But it reseted the `foo` jsonb column to `[]`.

How can I remove a given key like `bar` or only children key like `bar->abc` from a jsonb column with Laravel Eloquent?

(I'm using PostGreSQL database)

Answer (score 0):

I recommended you use $casts property in your model:

```
 protected $casts = [
    'foo'  => 'array',
];
```

to cast your column data to the array, then modify the result that is in the array format.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it with:

```
DB::connection('myconnection')
  ->statement("UPDATE myschema.users 
               SET    foo = foo::jsonb - 'bar'
               WHERE  id  = '123';"
  );
```